# sqlite python database error - no such table

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have made a database with a table called product. When I run the code below I get an error - sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: product.  I have used a database browser to check and the table does exist. Any ideas? The code and the file are both in the same folder. Thanks

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
import os.path

class Product:
    db_name = 'database.db'

    def __init__(self, wind):
        self.wind = wind
        self.wind.title('IT Products')

        frame = LabelFrame (self.wind, text = 'Add new record')
        frame.grid (row = 0, column = 1)

        Label (frame, text = 'Name: ').grid (row = 1, column = 1)
        self.name = Entry (frame)
        self.name.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        Label (frame, text = 'Price: ').grid (row = 2, column = 1)
        self.price = Entry (frame)
        self.price.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

        ttk.Button (frame, text= 'Add record').grid (row = 3, column =2 )
        self.message = Label (text = '',fg = 'red')
        self.message.grid (row = 3, column = 0)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview (height = 10, colum =2)
        self.tree.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text = 'Name', anchor = W)
        self.tree.heading(2, text = 'Price', anchor = W)

        ttk.Button (text = 'Delete record').grid (row = 5, column = 0)
        ttk.Button (text = 'Edit record').grid (row = 5, column = 1)

        self.viewing_records ()



    def run_query (self, query, parameters = ()): # database connection
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            query_result = cursor.execute (query, parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return query_result


    def viewing_records(self):
        records = self.tree.get_children()
        for element in records:
            self.tree.delete (element)
        query = 'SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY name DESC'
        db_rows = self.run_query (query)
        for row in db_rows:
            self.tree.insert ('', 0, text = row[1], values = row[2])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wind = Tk()
    application = Product (wind)
    wind.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
...
db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "database.db")
with sqlite3.connect('db_path') as conn:
...
```

You are creating a new database file with the name `'db_path'`.

Instead of

`with sqlite3.connect('db_path') as conn:`

you should have

`with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:`

Or in other words, use the variable `db_path` and not the literal string `'db_path'`.

For the sake of completeness, you may also want to use `Product.db_name` that you have already defined instead of hard-coding `'database.db'` again:

```
...
db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, self.db_name)
with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:
...
```

Comment: updated the code and removed that bit. still got the same issue :( thanks for the help

Comment: @maz86 Pay close attention to the code in the bottom of my answer. You are still passing the wrong value to `sqlite3.connect`

Comment: just tried and same error. BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, self.db_name)
             
        with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:

Answer (score 1):

This creates a variable called `db_path` which contains the path to the file `database.db`

```
db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "database.db")
```

But this uses the literal string `db_path` as the name of the database to connect to, *not* the contents of the variable you've just created:

```
with sqlite3.connect('db_path') as conn:
```

To use the variable, remove the quotes:

```
with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:
```

Comment: forgot to take those out! but still no luck

Comment: was only added to ensure it was checking the correct database Taken it out but no luckBASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "database.db")

Comment: @maz86 If you have modified your code and still get an error (same error or another one), please *update* the question with the latest code you have and the error you get.

Comment: Just updated. Thank you for your help. getting same error

Comment: @maz86 Pay close attention to the code in the bottom of my answer. You are still passing the wrong value to `sqlite3.connect`.

Comment: not sure where i am going wrong. sorry                                                                                                            def run_query (self, query, parameters = ()): # database connection
               
        
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            query_result = cursor.execute (query, parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return query_result

Comment: tried this too                                                                                                                     def run_query (self, query, parameters = ()): # database connection
               
        db_path = os.path.join( "database.db")
        with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            query_result = cursor.execute (query, parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return query_result